# Change border color on on-focus state in Select Component from Material-UI (React)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the styling of the `Select` Component on focus, from the Material-UI library. To clarify, `on focus`, not the normal border of the input, but once you have clicked an element of the dropdown (the on focus state)

This is what I achieved:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-cookies-4femm

I managed to change the background of the input on the `on focus` state. I can't achieve to style the border. What I have so far:

I've wrapped my component with a `ThemeProvider`:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme1}>
  My component
</ThemeProvider>
```

Where `theme1` is:

```
const theme1 = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiSelect: {
      select: {
        "&:focus": {
          backgroundColor: '#ffddec',
          color: 'brown'
        },
        '&:before': {
          borderColor: 'orange'
        },
        '&:after': {
          borderColor: 'green',
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

My Select component looks like this:

```
<Select
  labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
  id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  labelWidth={labelWidth}
>
```

When I click the dropdown, the only class that changes on the `Select` div is `Mui-focused`. I tried to style this class but didn't work.

`BackgroundColor` on `on focus` is working, but not the `borderColor` property. Any ideas why?

I found the behaviour that I want for the Input element, and here are the classes (see attached image)
It's the green border, it's applied on focus

[image]

Comment: Any online sample would be of great help.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-cookies-4femm I managed to change the background but not the color

Answer (score 2):

Replace color by borderColor in focus event.

```js
const theme1 = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiSelect: {
      select: {
        "&:focus": {
          backgroundColor: '#ffddec',
          borderColor: 'brown'
        },
        '&:before': {
          borderColor: 'orange'
        },
        '&:after': {
          borderColor: 'green',
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering. That was the first thing I tried, it's not working

Comment: As you can see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-cookies-4femm